# How to create .DOC file using PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, doc

This Question may be duplicate, but all I want to know that there is any way to create `.doc not .docx` file using PHP `(Not COM)`.
I've tried the following code to generate a file, It does but `it is not a real .doc file`, It is just a `masked HTML file`. Anybody please help me to create a `REAL .doc` file

Here is my Sample Code **(it generates .doc file but if you open it using notepad OR any other text editor YOU will find that it is not valid .doc file)**

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=file.doc");

    echo "<html>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<b>My first document</b><br />";
    echo "This is test document and this is created by using by PHP headers (Sample data)";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: http://www.livedocx.com/ supports .doc, .docx, .rtf and .pdf generation

Comment: can I do it using PHP (custom PHP) not livedocx.com as I've checked that already.

Comment: I'm not aware of any PHP library that creates BIFF format .doc files: I know a bit about Word Processing formats, and PHPWord only writes OfficeOpenXML .docx, OASIS .odt and Rich Text .rtf files

Answer (score 1):

Use this in header you will get your output

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyMsDocFile.doc');
```

Comment: any more explaination